# How can I index nested object using couchdb-lucene

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-lucene

Index function

When I try to index sub-property of `doc` in indexing function, like
`ret.add(doc.complaint.status, {field: 'status', type: 'string'})`
couchdb-lucene returns 500.

```js
function (doc) {
  var ret = new Document();

  ret.add(doc.customerName, {
    type: 'string',
    field: 'customerName'
  });

  ret.add(doc.complaint.status, {
    type: 'string',
    field: 'status'
  });

  ret.add(doc.complaint.numberOfCoupons, {
    type: 'int',
    field: 'numberOfCoupons'
  });

  return ret;
}
```

Object which exists in couchdb

`{
  "customerName": "Roman Maltsev",
  "complaint": {
    "status": "In progress",
    "numberOfCoupons": 10
  }
}`

Query using proxy
`GET http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/complaints-management-rom/_design/find/all?q=status:"In progress"`
returns 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was that lucene index each document, including _design/view itself, so I need just check does property exists or not